# Unusual elixir.vim auto indentation for case

Tags: vim, elixir

Using autoindent in vim with the elixir.vim plugin I'm getting the following: [image: Vim auto indent]

Using the :set command I get the following:

[image: set result]

These options look right to me, expecially indentexpr. Why am I getting such weird formatting in the case block?

Additional detail: I'm using neovim, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I believe that you should report issue on https://github.com/elixir-lang/vim-elixir.

Comment: The reason I didn't do that is I'm not sure if the issue is my configuration. I thought they would surely already be aware of this if it is a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't make the assumption that they're already aware of it (assuming it is an issue with the vim binding).